# How to add new ACF repeater row after removing all rows using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, advanced-custom-fields

I am creating a **custom ACF Field** within a page edit screen which I have added a **div container**, outside the container is **3 buttons**. Add text block, add image and save.

I also have a **repeater field** (I will later be hiding from view) which I am **populating dynamically** when the user clicks save.

This is all working however when trying to integrate **removing the rows prior to adding** the new rows through js The **acf repeater breaks** and does not add the row. As a result the fields cannot be found and I get a **undefined js error**.

I have tried multiple methods including:
setTimeout()
.delay()
changing the order things were being fired but to no avail.

I can see the array is correctly populating the data through the console log however as the new row is not opening its not able to pair up with the corresponding acf repeater sub-field.

If I comment out the remove rows step and only add new rows and populate the data it works however this causes teh content to double up each time the save button is clicked.

**How can I remove all ACF repeater fields for a specific repeater prior to adding new rows from the data array successfully.**

Within my function I am:

Removing all acf fields by triggering the event clicks on the corresponding buttons.

```
 $('[data-key="my_acf_repeater_field"] tr td.remove a[data-event="remove-row"]').trigger('click');
 $('div.acf-tooltip a[data-event="confirm"]').trigger('click');
```

The array is then built out within a jquery .each(function)

```
 let data = {
    'item_type' : item_type,
    'height' : height_num,
    'width' : width_final,
    'left' : left_final,
    'top' : top_num,
    'content' : content,
    'image' : image
 };
```

This is passed to another function where I first run

```
 console.log(data); // this successfully displays the array in the console.
```

I then attempt to load the new row.

(NOTE: if I comment out the remove rows step and only run the add new rows function the following does successfully add a new row and the data populates in the fields correctly.)

```
 $('[data-key="my_acf_repeater_field"] div.acf-actions a[data-event="add-row"]').trigger('click');
```

Once I load the new rows I am populating the fields

```
 // update ACF item type
 let item_type = acf.getFields({name: 'item_type'});
 item_type.slice(-1)[0].val(data['item_type']);

 // Update ACF height
 let height = acf.getFields({name: 'height'});
 height.slice(-1)[0].val(data['height']);

 // Update ACF width
 let width = acf.getFields({name: 'width'});
 width.slice(-1)[0].val(data['width']);

 // Update ACF left position
 let left = acf.getFields({name: 'left_position'});
 left.slice(-1)[0].val(data['left']);

 // Update ACF top position
 let top = acf.getFields({name: 'top_position'});
 top.slice(-1)[0].val(data['top']);

 // Update ACF text content
 let text = acf.getFields({name: 'text_content'});
 text.slice(-1)[0].val(data['content']);

 // Update ACF image array
 let img = acf.getFields({name: 'image'});
 img.slice(-1)[0].val(data['image']);
```